# Extract/Export Data from an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, export

We have an Oracle Forms 6i app right now and we would like to export the data from the database because we are changing the whole system. So how can we export the data?

Thanks

Comment: Get your DBA to do a dump

Comment: Unfortunately, we have no DBA and that's why I'm asking. Is there a specific way to dump it?

Comment: Q has nothing to do with Forms. Also, there are so many different methods you could choose from, so we need more details about what your requirements are.

Comment: Well, what we exactly are trying to do is that we need to export all data into excel or any other format to import it into another DB. That is the goal